# Is there a good way to combine resolvers for multiple GraphQL objects, preferably using graphql-js?

Tags: graphql, graphql-js

Suppose you have a GraphQL layer, written on node.js using graphql-js, that communicates with a SQL database. Suppose you have the following simple types and fields:

- Store
  A single brick-and-mortar location for a chain of grocery stores.
  Fields:

  - id: GraphQLID
  - region: StoreRegion
  - employees: GraphQLList(Employee)
- StoreRegion
  A GraphQLEnumType containing the list of regions into which the chain divides its stores.
  Values:

  - NORTHEAST
  - MIDATLANTIC
  - SOUTHEAST
  - ...
- Employee
  Represents a single employee working at a store.
  Fields:

  - id: GraphQLID
  - name: GraphQLString
  - salary: GraphQLFloat

Suppose the API exposes a `store` query that accepts a Region and returns a list of Store objects. Now suppose the client sends this query:

```
{
    store(region: NORTHEAST) {
        employees {
            name
            salary
        }
    }
}
```

Hopefully this is all pretty straightforward so far.

So here's my question, and I hope (expect, really) that it's something that has a common solution and I'm just having trouble finding it because my Google-Fu is weak today: is there a good way that can I write the resolvers for these types such that I can wrap up all the requested fields for all the employees from all the returned stores into a single SQL query statement, resulting in one round-trip to the database of the form:

```
SELECT name,salary FROM employees WHERE id IN (1111, 1133, 2177, ...)
```

rather than making one request per employee or even one request per store?

This is really a concrete instance of a more general question: is there a good way to combine resolvers to avoid making multiple requests in cases where they could be easily combined?

I'm asking this question in terms of graphql-js because that's what I'm hoping to work with, and since I figure that would allow for more specific answers, but if there's a more implementation-agnostic answer, that would be cool too.

Comment: While definitely possible, this is essentially optimizing for one particular query to your API. Unless you already know *for sure* that you'll run into performance issues *as soon as you deploy*, it's probable most pragmatic to use simple resolvers and optimize problem queries once they become a problem :-) Otherwise you'll likely end up with many single-use optimizations that make changes far more difficult.

Answer (score 2):

So, basically you are wondering how you can combine multiple resolvers into fewer database queries. This is trying to solve what they call the [N+1 query problem](https://secure.phabricator.com/book/phabcontrib/article/n_plus_one/). Here’s at least two ways you can solve this.

1. [DataLoader](https://github.com/graphql/dataloader): This is a more general solution and it's created by Facebook. You could use this to batch multiple queries that query a single item of a single type into a single query that queries multiple items of a single type. In your example you would batch all employees into a single DB query and you would still have a separate query for getting the store. Here's a [video by Ben Awad that explains DataLoader](https://youtu.be/2cSVIWDUSn4)
2. [JoinMonster](https://join-monster.readthedocs.io/en/latest/): Specifically for SQL. Will do JOINs to make one SQL query per graphql query. Here's a [video by Ben Awad explaining JoinMonster](https://youtu.be/n-Mb2HiFVKc)

Comment: Using `DataLoader` we would get 4 requests total, correct? 1 request to gather all the stores, and another request, one to get all the employees, and then 2 more requests -- one to get all the salaries and another to get all the names. 4 requests seems like a lot.